# How can I stop table corruption on MySQL 5.6.14 for Windows Server 2012

Tags: mysql

I have a MyISAM table that gets truncated and filled with data every day.  In the last few days, queries against the table run very slowly.  If I create a new table with the same schema and dump the same data in, queries against this table run normal speed, until the next morning when it gets truncated and refilled, then it runs slowly again.  This is now the copied table that was running fast.

Does anyone know how to stop this?

Thanks!
Scott

Comment: sounds like a fragmentation issue

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!

Comment: Great. I will put it as an answer so you can mark it as correct in case others need it

Answer (score 0):

A table that builds up can suffer from fragmentation, the reason drop and recreate works is it allocates the space in one go.

This seems more obvious under windows than unix .

Defrag